# Python and multiple select with a ListCtrl

Tags: python, select, wxpython, listctrl

I have a custom listctrl in my application that I would like the ability to select multiple rows (and deselect) much like one would do in a ListBox.  Currently I have a listctrl that I am able to grab single selections; however, once I click on another row in my listctrl, the previous "un-highlights".  I would like it to stay highlighted unless I click on it again -- so the user knows which rows he/she has selected (exact same way a ListBox works).  I tried adding `wx.LC_MULTIPLE_SEL` to the listctrl line, but this did not work.

Help?  Thanks!

I took this example from the following site by Mike Driscoll [Python Blog](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/01/04/wxpython-wx-listctrl-tips-and-tricks/).  I adapted to it to grab row selections.  Essentially I select a row and the index is appended to a list called `InfoList`.  When I select a new row, it appends correctly, but I would like the row to stay "highlighted" in the actual list.  Then I could add another line to remove an item from the list if I select it again in the listctrl.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl as listmix

InfoList = []

musicdata = {
0 : ("Bad English", "The Price Of Love", "Rock"),
1 : ("DNA featuring Suzanne Vega", "Tom's Diner", "Rock"),
2 : ("George Michael", "Praying For Time", "Rock"),
3 : ("Gloria Estefan", "Here We Are", "Rock"),
4 : ("Linda Ronstadt", "Don't Know Much", "Rock"),
5 : ("Michael Bolton", "How Am I Supposed To Live Without You", "Blues"),
6 : ("Paul Young", "Oh Girl", "Rock"),
}

########################################################################
class TestListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, ID=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                 size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, style)

########################################################################
class TestListCtrlPanel(wx.Panel, listmix.ColumnSorterMixin):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)

        self.list_ctrl = TestListCtrl(self, size=(-1,100),
                         style=wx.LC_REPORT
                         |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                         |wx.LC_SORT_ASCENDING
                         )
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, "Artist")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, "Title", wx.LIST_FORMAT_RIGHT)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, "Genre")

        items = musicdata.items()
        index = 0
        for key, data in items:
            self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(index, data[0])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 1, data[1])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 2, data[2])
            self.list_ctrl.SetItemData(index, key)
            index += 1

        # Now that the list exists we can init the other base class,
        # see wx/lib/mixins/listctrl.py
        self.itemDataMap = musicdata
        listmix.ColumnSorterMixin.__init__(self, 3)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_COL_CLICK, self.OnColClick, self.list_ctrl)

        ### I ADDED THIS ###
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, self.OnSelectMustHave, self.list_ctrl)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    ### I ADDED THIS ###
    def OnSelectMustHave(self,event):        
        info = event.GetData()
        InfoList.append(info)
        print info,InfoList

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Used by the ColumnSorterMixin, see wx/lib/mixins/listctrl.py
    def GetListCtrl(self):
        return self.list_ctrl

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnColClick(self, event):
        print "column clicked"
        event.Skip()

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "List Control Tutorial")

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = TestListCtrlPanel(self)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I added working code above (mine was way too long and involved to simply add).

Comment: If i directly copy/paste your code(above) it works fine for me to select multiples on windows7 ... what OS are you on?

Comment: Windows 8...please don't tell me this is another thing I must dislike about windows 8!

Comment: you need to hold control or shift in order to select multiples ...

Comment: I figured...was hoping there was another way.  Thanks!

Comment: see my answer ... you should just be able to run that do_select ... but for some reason the selected event continues propagating and ends up just selecting the most recent so you have to wait for that and then select all ... there is probably a better way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its gross but this will do what you want

```
def OnSelectMustHave(self,event):        
    info = event.GetData()
    InfoList.append(info)
    def do_select():
          map(lambda x:self.list_ctrl.Select(x,1) ,set(InfoList))

    wx.CallLater(100,do_select)
    print info,InfoList
    return
```

however since you have the list of selected elements in InfoList something like the below solution may work

```
def OnSelectMustHave(self,event):        
    info = event.GetData()
    InfoList.append(info)
    map(lambda x:self.list_ctrl.SetItemBackgroundColour(x,wx.LIGHT_GREY) ,set(InfoList))
    print info,InfoList
    return
```

Answer (score 1):

A regular ListCtrl works:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "List Control Tutorial")

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.index = 0

        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(-1,100),
                         style=wx.LC_REPORT
                         |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                         )
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Subject')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Due')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Location', width=125)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Add Line")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_line)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def add_line(self, event):
        line = "Line %s" % self.index
        self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index, line)
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, "01/19/2010")
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 2, "USA")
        self.index += 1

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

And if I modify this to use the two mixins you mentioned, it also works:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl as listmix

########################################################################
class MyListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.TextEditMixin, listmix.ColumnSorterMixin):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        listmix.ColumnSorterMixin.__init__(self, 3)
        listmix.TextEditMixin.__init__(self)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def GetListCtrl(self):
        return self

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "List Control Tutorial")

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.index = 0

        self.list_ctrl = MyListCtrl(panel)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Subject')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Due')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Location', width=125)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Add Line")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_line)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def add_line(self, event):
        line = "Line %s" % self.index
        self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index, line)
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, "01/19/2010")
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 2, "USA")
        self.index += 1

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I am using wxPython 2.6 and wxPython 2.8.12 on Windows 7. I can select multiple items one at a time and deselect them as well.

Comment: I should have been more detailed.  I'm not sure how you are selecting multiple lines.  They way I see it is to hold "ctrl" down and select.  I'm hoping there is a different way around this where I can just left click on each one individually and they all stay highlighted.